# perl-selenium: how to extend Test::WWW::Selenium object with custom methods?

Tags: perl, testing, selenium, api-design

Using perl and TAP, I have written a lot of selenium tests and saved them in *.t files.

I have created some helper  functions, put them into a non-object oriented  package, say My::Util::SeleniumHelper.

All functions are exported from this module.
In the beginning, one package was sufficient, now the single-module API contains quite a few unrelated functions. These functions are called, for example make_sel(),
  head_ok(),
  cms_logout(),
  cms_login(),
  cms_clickthru_simple(),
  selenium_rc_running(),
  treecontrol_toggles() - you get the idea.

Moreover, many blocks of code in the t-files are still redundant, making the .t file look like a template.

Thus, I want to give my *.t code a more OO design.

**Any ideas on how to design the new API?**

**Essentially, I am also looking for code examples (here, or on the internet) where someone has extended the selenium object in a clever way. It does not have to be in perl.**

Would it be useful to add methods to the  Test::WWW::Selenium object $sel?

```
$sel->my_click_ok()
```

I should I try to override the $sel object?, Deriving a Test::WWW::Selenium::Customized class from Test::WWW::Selenium

This would violate the ["Prefer composition over inheritance" idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Should I wrap the selenium object into another object using composition?

```
$myobj->{sel}->click_ok()
```

Here are some more requirements or thoughts:

I also want to use the [pageObjects Pattern/Idiom](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects). Not doing so yet.
Maybe so

```
$myobj->{current_page}->loginbox
```

or

```
$myobj->do_stuff($current_page->loginbox)
```

I noted that in most cases, basically, I'd like to give the selenium method something like an Moose's around() modifier.  Do th standard thing, but do some things before and after.

However, I prefer to not use Moose here because the tests need to run on a few different machines, and  don't want to install Moose and all its dependencies on all these PCs. I am not saying that is  impossible to use moose, however I did not yet use non-moose objects (Test::WWW::Selenium) and moose objects together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Moose and [delegation](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Moose-2.0007/lib/Moose/Manual/Delegation.pod) to extend Test::WWW::Selenium.  The only thing thats in the extension is configuration stuff (host, port, browser, etc).  Everything else is in roles.

Answer (score 1):

Making a custom class inheriting from the Selenium one seems completely reasonable in this case.   Eric's Moose delegation solution is a little cleaner; but a bit more complicated too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm subclassing Test::WWW::Selenium. new {} needs to call SUPER, but then on, it looks and tastes like the parent. I've got a new open() that lints the HTML and checks links (memoized of course).